# jspdf unable to print the entire html table canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to convert html table to pdf using jspdf but the problem is jspdf cannot capture the entire table when it contains data that can span multiple pages . is there a way that jspdf can split html canvas into multiple pages?

below is what I did on html:
Itis a table that displays the data that comes from the database. so when data is less, the entire html canvas can be displayed on pdf but when the data increases all the data cannot be captured.

```
 <div class="container-fluid px-4" id="transactions">
                        <img src="pl-removebg-preview.png" class="img-fluid logo" style="margin-top:5%; margin-left:35%;">
                        <h4 style="justify-content:center; text-align: center; margin-top:5%;">Transactions report from <b id="from"> </b> to <b id="to"> </b></h4>
                        <div class="row my-5">
                            <div class="col table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="font-size:15px;">Merchant Name</th>
                                            <th style=" font-size:15px;">Distributor Number</th>
                                            <th style="font-size:15px;">Provider</th>
                                            <th style="font-size:15px;">Customer Merchant</th>
                                            <th style="font-size:15px;">Date</th>
                                            <th style="font-size:15px;">Status</th>
                                            <th style="font-size:15px;">Amount</th> 
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="client_data"  style="font-size:10px;">
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr style="font-size:10px;">
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Total</th>
                                            <th id="total"></th>    
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

below is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var form = $('#transactions'),
    cache_width = form.width(),
    a4 = [610.28, 841.89]; // for a4 size paper width and height  

  $('#create_pdf').on('click', function () {
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    createPDF();
  });

  function createPDF() {
  
    event.preventDefault();
    getCanvas().then(function (canvas) {
      var
        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
        doc = new jsPDF({
          unit: 'px',
          format: 'a4'
        });
      doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 5, 5);
      doc.save('Pay_Lesotho_Report.pdf');
      form.width(cache_width);
    });
  }

  function getCanvas() {
    form.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');
    return html2canvas(form.get(0), {
      imageTimeout: 2000,
      removeContainer: true
    });
  }
});
```

this above code works well, I need help in converting html canvas into multiple pages on a pdf